# SQL Table design for users who can leave feedback to users

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I am designing a website where users can post certain things, and other users can bid on it. So after everything is settled, they can leave review to each other for that lets call it "job". In table feedback I think I need to have 2 Userids, one of the person who left feedback and one of the person who received feedback.  When a user leaves a review, it makes more sense to create FK on UserId of receiver, because those feedbacks will be viewed on receiver profile page.

Or maybe I got completely wrong approach on this?

[image]

Comment: You left feedback to product, so you need: author_id, product_id. author_id should have fk to Users table, and product_id to Products. There no need "receiver user_id", because you can get it through product table.

Comment: I left feedback to user. And i want others to be able to view this user profile and all his feedbacks and people who left feedback to this author

Comment: i just saw productID in your table feedback and was thinking its about product. Because if you left feedback to user then you probably not need productID?
You can get all feedbacks in user profile if just joining feedback table with products by ProductID and set filter by UserID (in Products table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In table feedback I think I need to have 2 Userids, one of the person who leave feedback and one of person who received feedback

A feedback is related to two users: a sender (that leaves the feedback) and a receiver. To represent that relationship, you would need to have two foreign keys in the `Feedbacks` table that reference the `Users` table. That way, you can enforce integrity across tables (and ensure that every sender and receiver *is* a valid user). Each feedback is also related to a product, but it seems like you already have that relationship in mind.

So:

```
Feedbacks
    ReceiverId        foreign key to Users(UserId)
    SenderId          foreign key to Users(UserId)
    ProductId         foreign key to Products(ProductId) 
    ...
```

Comment: yea, this was my doubt.. should I have 2 fk on same table.. but now when i think it.. why shouldnt I? Thanks man

Comment: Welcome @drmausama! Foreign keys are there to guarantee data integrity, so they really make sense here.